# Stopping client to send packets to server

Tags: python

There is Multi-client server situation in which a server is connected to multiple clients.
All the clients are messaging the server and the server is replying them well.
Now if one of the client floods the server with numerous packets then the server just stops receiving those packets from that client and still receives packets from other clients connected to it.
.Please help me doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to close the socket immediately after accepting it, if the connection comes form the banned client:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    if addr[0] in banned_clients:
        conn.close()
    else:
        proceed()
```

Comment: if I close the socket then I cant receive messages from other clients connected to the server.

Comment: don't close the server socket, only the connection that is opened for each client.

Comment: Sir, if i have used UDP sockets then I don't then how can I close the connection??

Comment: sorry, didn't know you want UDP.

Comment: then how we will do this with UDP sockets?? as UDP sockets are connectionless and there is no connection so then how will that client be disconnected??